# Display external content in own website (simulate browser as a Web app)

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I would like to build a Web application that provides additional information about website "on the fly". For example, users go to my website but there they can browse other pages, e.g., within an `iframe` as the main part of my site. But now, depending on the website the user is currently browsing on, I also want to display additional information like some comments or ratings associated with that site.

The solution using an `iframe` to display the external pages would be straightforward. However, due to security isses, there's no way to keep track of the currently loaded URL in the `iframe` if the URL is not of the domain as the parent page. As soon as a user would click on a link in the external page, my parent page would not know the new location an could not update the additional information accordingly.

I've tried some simple workarounds, includung using a PHP script `grab.php` to fetch and display external content:

```
<?php
  $ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  echo $content;
?>
```

Then the `src` of the `iframe` would always be something like

```
<iframe src="grab.php?url=http://www.google.com" width="1200" height="800"></iframe>
```

This comes with several problems though. Firstly, relative source, e.g., to images, point to a location with my domain and are therefore not displayed. Secondly, I would also need to tweak all relative and absolute links contained in the external page to something like `grab.php?url=...`. And lastly, this doesn't work with content the external page has to load dynamically. The last point seems to be a major buzzkill.

My question is now, is there *any* way this could be realized?

(I currently have a solution using a browser extension which opens a popup window to show the additional information. But obviously the extension is browser dependent, and an alternative solution that doesn't require users to install an extension at all would be great. Everything would be trivial if I could get the current URL of the `iframe`).

Comment: maybe get rid of the iframe and try to parse the child page with cURL to substitute the content of the whole document with the one from the wanted page + the additional futures of your code

Comment: Care to elaborate? To be honest, I cannot quite get the idea. Since it is still using cURL, doesn't the issue with dynamically loaded content still prevail?

Comment: If you are using php only to get the remote page's data there will be no problem, you can even log-in a certain page and get the data you need with cURL. You'll need to tweak the head section to include your scripts and the rest of the page can be left as is (with the addition of the html and css of your widget), also parsing the links and image src's to be absolute when they are relative.